# Wireless connection works but the internet is too slow to use in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, wireless

The internet is so slow as to be unusable. And I'm not being picky. Even after minutes I can't get my Google home page to load. I tried installing a package through apt-get and was getting rates between 0 and a few hundred bytes/s. That's bytes, not kilobytes! Mostly 0 however (no exaggeration, it spends large amounts of time stalled). And I would go to a speed test web site of some kind but I can't since nothing will load.

Briefly put, the laptop I am using was connected to two wireless networks while using Ubuntu 11.04 without any issues before this. It was also connected to a wired network without any issues. It dual boats Windows 7 which has never had any issues, not even with the current wireless network.

Just to be clear, on the current wi-fi network, Windows 7 encounters no issues (speedtest.net puts the network speed at 1mb/s) but my network connection in Ubuntu 11.04 is so slow as to literally be unusable.

I am unfamiliar with the router except for the fact that it boasts a Rogers logo (that's a large ISP/cable provider in Canada for those not familiar with the land of igloos and polar bears). I am far from the router and some desktop widget I use tells me the signal strength is at 58% (it seems fairly reliable and this would appear to match up with the filled bars in the network icon).

I should also mention I'm just renting a room in this house so I'm not the network administrator and while I can access the 192.168.0.1 router page, the password wasn't set to 'password' so it's not much use to me.

Here are a bunch of commands I ran which don't tell me a whole lot but I thought might be more instructive to the wise around here:

lspci (just showing my network card):

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

This one is self explanatory.

```
PING www.googele.com (216.65.41.185) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nnw.net (216.65.41.185): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=267 ms
64 bytes from nnw.net (216.65.41.185): icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=190 ms
64 bytes from nnw.net (216.65.41.185): icmp_req=3 ttl=51 time=212 ms
64 bytes from nnw.net (216.65.41.185): icmp_req=4 ttl=51 time=207 ms
64 bytes from nnw.net (216.65.41.185): icmp_req=5 ttl=51 time=220 ms

--- www.googele.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 190.079/219.699/267.963/26.121 ms
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:6a:8a:02:20:da  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:42 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:960 (960.0 B)  TX bytes:960 (960.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:7c:8f:05:c6:bf  
          inet addr:192.168.0.16  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::227c:8fff:fe05:c6bf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:982 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:658 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:497250 (497.2 KB)  TX bytes:95076 (95.0 KB)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The answer from the blog is:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

The blog then went on to describe how to automate that command. Using any editor, open `/etc/pm/power.d/wireless`

```
# Command line
sudo -e /etc/pm/power.d/wireless

# gedit
gksu gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

And add in the following line

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

And the final tip is to edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Search for the hosts line

`hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

and change it to

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Answer (score -1):

Please read this  blog.... [link](http://www.hitxp.com/articles/software/ubuntu-fix-slow-wireless-internet-connection-speed-upgrading-11-04-natty-narwhal/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Comment: You have also included a link.. :D 
Any-way thanks for update.....

Comment: @ManishTrivedi The link in htorque's comment **included the essential message; the link was present for reference**. In contrast, your post has no substance *besides* the link. We're not against links. We just think answers should answer the question, rather than refer generically to some other answer somewhere else.